# Cause thread release a memory leak?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have a multi threading code. This is a simple example of my code:

```
void SomeClass::ExampleForThread2()
{
  m_thread_ptr = std::make_unique<std::thread>([=]() {
    while (! m_stop)
    {
      try
      {
        // ... do work
      }
      catch (...)
      {
        // ...
      }
    }
#pragma messsage(__DBG__"TODO: not known if release results in a mem leak. Please investigate.")
    //m_thread_ptr.reset(); // now exception will be raised during destruction of std::thread
    m_thread_ptr.release(); // no exception. Will there be a Memory leak for std::thread ?
    });
}
```

If m_stop is true, the while loop stops. Will thread2 than cleaned up automatically? In that case I can do release and there is no memory leak. But is that true?

My answer is now:

```
void SomeClass::ExampleForThread2()
{
if (m_thread_ptr != nullptr)
{
   if (m_thread_ptr->joinable())
   {
      m_tread_ptr->join()
   }  
}
.......
```

And I deleted this part:

```
#pragma messsage(__DBG__"TODO: not known if release results in a mem leak. Please investigate.")
    //m_thread_ptr.reset(); // now exception will be raised during destruction of std::thread
    m_thread_ptr.release(); // no exception. Will there be a Memory leak for std::thread ?
    });
```

The function is single threaded and don't need a lock.

Comment: std::thread ain't made to dynamically allocate, don't use std::make_unique with it.

Comment: You want to look into the method called join

Comment: And in C++20 you should use std::jthread

Comment: Thanks, I follow the flow of the method join and that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

`m_thread_ptr.reset` will try to destroy your thread object when it is still joinable. This is a guaranteed call to `std::terminate`.
`m_thread_ptr.release` is a memory leak, yes: you extract the pointer from the `unique_ptr` object and then drop it on the floor.

Just let the function "run out" and let `SomeClass`' destructor clean up the remaining thread state.